# Best synchronization strategy to block worker threads when a database is down

Tags: java, multithreading

Multiple workers are processing from a queue and when a database failure occurs it will contact a supervisor that will then lock all worker threads and poll the database at an interval until it is up and it will then release all the threads so they can continue processing. The worker threads can either advance or wait with the processing and the supervisor thread can lock or unlock.

I was thinking of an interface like this. What synchronization primitives would you use? Actors would be a good solution but i don't have the time for a rewrite.

```
public interface Latch {

    /**
     * This method will cause a thread(s) to only advance if the latch is in an open state. If the
     * latch is closed the thread(s) will wait until the latch is open before they can advance.
     */
    void advanceWhenOpen();

    /**
     * Close the latch forcing all threads that reaches the latch's advance method to wait until
     * its open again.
     */
    void close();

    /**
     * Opens the latch allowing blocked threads to advance.
     */
    void open();

    boolean isOpen();
}
```

Comment: Probably this question should go to CodeReview.

Comment: i have not implemented it yet and im looking for different strategies of solving the problem.

Comment: @mkrakhin CodeReview requires a working implementation to be reviewed, and this is just a (draft version of) an interface.

Comment: @Pimgd but he already has some ideas.

Comment: Stub code is off-topic at CR.

Comment: @mkrakhin It takes more than ideas to be on topic, it requires full-blown working code.

Comment: Well. It seems I have some misunderstanding regarding CR. Sorry.

Comment: What kind of queue are you using? A `BlockingQueue` would do this for you.

Comment: No problem.  We like educating people.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not really a "latch" - at least the "Java Concurrency in Practice" book says that "Once the latch reaches the terminal state, it cannot change state again, so it remains open forever."

But you can use CountDownLatch objects in the background - whenever your "Latch" needs to be closed, then you can create a new CountDownLatch object with the count of one and await() on in in your advanceWhenOpen(). I think that from a readability point of view this would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) as the synchronization primitive for this purpose.  The advantage of a read/write lock as opposed to a simple monitor or mutex is that multiple threads can hold the read lock at any given time.  This is advantageous when you have lots of readers (e.g. your thread pool in this case) and only one or few writers (e.g. the thread checking for open/close of the database).

With a single monitor or mutex, your threads will serialize on the one lock, making that section of code contentious.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to proxy the queue to make it pausable when the database is unavailable. Workers can check the paused state of the queue while processing and, if necessary, wait for it to unpause. A basic code-demonstration:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class PausableQueue<T> {

    LinkedBlockingQueue<T> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<T>();
    AtomicReference<CountDownLatch> pause = new AtomicReference<CountDownLatch>(new CountDownLatch(0));

    public T take() throws InterruptedException {

        awaitPause();
        return q.take();
    }

    public void awaitPause() throws InterruptedException {
        pause.get().await();
    }

    public void setPaused(boolean paused) {

        if (paused) {
            // only update if there are no threads waiting on current countdown-latch
            if (!isPaused()) {
                pause.set(new CountDownLatch(1));
            }
        } else {
            pause.get().countDown();
        }
    }

    public boolean isPaused() {
        return (pause.get().getCount() > 0L);
    }

    /* *** Test the pausable queue *** */

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        try {
            testPause(executor);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }

    private static void testPause(ExecutorService executor) throws Exception {

        final PausableQueue<Object> q = new PausableQueue<Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            q.q.add(new Object());
        }
        final CountDownLatch tfinished = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Runnable taker = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                println("Taking an object.");
                try {
                    Object o = q.take();
                    println("Got an object: " + o);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    tfinished.countDown();
                }
            }
        };

        executor.execute(taker);
        tfinished.await();
        final CountDownLatch tstarted2 = new CountDownLatch(2);
        final CountDownLatch tfinished2 = new CountDownLatch(2);
        taker = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                println("Taking an object.");
                tstarted2.countDown();
                try {
                    Object o = q.take();
                    println("Got an object: " + o);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    tfinished2.countDown();
                }
            }
        };
        q.setPaused(true);
        println("Queue paused");
        executor.execute(taker);
        executor.execute(taker);
        tstarted2.await();
        // Pause to show workers pause too
        Thread.sleep(100L);
        println("Queue unpausing");
        q.setPaused(false);
        tfinished2.await();
        // "Got an object" should show a delay of at least 100 ms.
    }

    private static void println(String s) {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " - " + s);
    }

}
```